# GAPI Export to Google Sheet Invalid Argument Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-sheets, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to export details from out app into a google sheet and am getting an "Invalid argument" error. I'm trying to take the data from the page and also grab users' birthdays on export. We use firestore as a db.

```
exportStaff(shift) {
      console.log(shift)
      const exportHeaders = [
        "Day",
        "Event",
        "Position",
        "Start",
        "End",
        "First Name",
        "Last Name",
        "Phone",
        "Email",
        "Confirmed",
        "DOB",
        "Code",
      ];
      const exportItems = [];
      for (var key in this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)) {

        function myDOB(staff) {
          return fb.usersCollection.doc(staff).get()
          .then(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data().dob)
            return doc.data().dob
          })
        }

        exportItems.push([
          shift.day,
          shift.event,
          shift.position.title,
          shift.startTime,
          shift.endTime,
          this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].firstName,
          this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].lastName,
          this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].phone,
          this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].email,
          this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].confirmed,
          myDOB(this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].userId),
          `=REGEXEXTRACT(H2,"....$")`
        ])
      }
     
      this.$gapi.getGapiClient().then(gapi => {
        const exportService = new ExportService(exportHeaders, Object.values(exportItems), gapi);
        exportService.export();
      });
    },
```

All of the birthdays are logging correctly to the console, but no values show on the sheet.

Here is a screenshot of the error in the console.

[image]

How can I get the birthdays (DOB) to export properly?

Here is my exportService.js

```
export default class ExportService {
    constructor(columns, data, gapi) {
        this.columns = columns;
        this.data = data;
        this.gapi = gapi;
        this.spreadsheetId = null;
    }

    export() {
        this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
            .then(() => {
                this.createSpreadsheet();
            });
    }

    createSpreadsheet() {
        this.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({
            properties: {
                title: 'New Report'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            this.spreadsheetId = response.result.spreadsheetId;
            this.writeRows();
            this.openSpreadsheet(response.result.spreadsheetUrl)
        });
    }

    writeRows() {
        this.data.unshift(this.columns);
        this.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId: this.spreadsheetId,
            range: 'A1:F1',
            valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
            resource: {
                values: this.data
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            var result = response.result;
            console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`)
        });
    }

    openSpreadsheet(url) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed request of `exportService.export()`?

Comment: Hey there I updated the question to include that part of the code

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, I thought that it is required to confirm the value of `this.data`. So can you provide the sample values of `this.data` for replicating your issue? For I saw your image, I'm worried that your value of `myDOB(this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].userId)` might be the reason for your issue.

Comment: this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].userId is just the firebase user uid

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, the value of `myDOB(this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].userId)` is a string value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes it is. Alphanumeric uid

Comment: Thank you for replying. When the value of `myDOB(this.orderedPlacedUsers2(shift.id)[key].userId)` is the string value, I think that no error occurs. So in order to correctly replicate your issue, can you provide the sample values of `this.data`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: function myDOB(r) {
          console.log(r)
          return fb.usersCollection.doc(r).get()
          .then(doc => {
            console.log(dob)
            return doc.data().dob
          })
        }

Comment: Here's an example Kv3x8VFM4Ma5FcSMPK0EL5sftb93

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had asked about the sample value of `this.data`. But from `function myDOB(r) { console.log(r) return fb.usersCollection.doc(r).get() .then(doc => { console.log(dob) return doc.data().dob }) }` and `Here's an example Kv3x8VFM4Ma5FcSMPK0EL5sftb93`, unfortunately, I cannot understand the value of `this.data`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to try to think of the solution.

Comment: Check row 1 column 10 of the values in the resource you pass to spreadsheets.values.append. If you could post a sample of what this value is (the `this.data` you pass to is, like Tanaike asked) it would be helpful for honing in on the problem